# Delete all contents and child elements of an xml node using element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file and want to delete all content within nodes with a give attribute=value but have been unable to get the element tree `.remove()` method to work. I get a `list.remove(x): x not in list` error.

If I have a div, containing multiple paragraphs and list elements, with attributes `v1-9,deleted` I want to be able to delete the whole div and all it's contents.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#get target file
tree = ET.parse('tested.htm')
#pull into element tree
root = tree.getroot()
#confirm output
print(root)
#define xlmns tags
MadCap = {'MadCap': 'http://www.madcapsoftware.com/Schemas/MadCap.xsd'}

i=1
j=6

# specify state
            state = "state.deleted-in-vers"
            # specify version
            vers = "version-number.v{}-{}".format(i,j)
            # combine to get conditional string might need to double up b/c of order mattering here???
            search = ".//*[@MadCap:conditions='{},{}']".format(vers,state)
            #get matching elements
            for elem in root.findall(search, MadCap):
                print('---PARENT---')
                print(elem)
                print('attributes:', elem.attrib)
                print('text:', elem.text)
                elem.text = " "
                elem.attrib = {}
                for child in elem.iter():
                    print('-child element-')
                    print(child)
                    elem.remove(child)
            print('==========')
```

I've omitted the loops over i and j in the above for simplicity.

Here's a snippet of the target xml so you can see how these attributes are used.

```
<div MadCap:conditions="state.deleted-in-vers,version-number.v1-9"> 
                              <h4>Example with password prompts</h4> 
                              <p>In the following example:</p> 
                              <ul> 
                                  <li>We have included the value <code>connection.ask-pass</code>, so are being prompted for the password of the setup user. </li> 
                                  <li>This host has an installation user <code>hub-setup</code>. </li> 
                                  <li>We are installing to the host <code>hub.example.com</code>. We must provide the FQDN of the host.</li> 
                                  <li>The KeyStore we are installing to the <MadCap:variable name="Components/gateway-hub.gateway-hub-name" /> hosts is located at <code>/tmp/ssl_keystore</code> on the installation machine.</li> 
                                  <li>The TrustStore we are installing to the <MadCap:variable name="Components/gateway-hub.gateway-hub-name" /> hosts is located at <code>/tmp/ssl_truststore</code> on the installation machine.</li> 
                                  <li>We are not providing any of the password key-value pairs, and therefore are being prompted for the passwords. </li> 
                                  <li>This host has a runtime user <code>hub</code>.<ul><li>The runtime user is in group <code>gateway-hub</code>.</li></ul></li> 
                              </ul> 
                              <p>The <MadCap:variable name="3rd-party-products/formats.json-name" /> configuration file is the following:</p><pre xml:space="preserve">{ 
      "connection": { 
          "ask_pass": true, 
          "user": "hub-setup" 
      }, 
      "hosts": ["hub.example.com"], 
      "hub": {<MadCap:conditionalText MadCap:conditions="state.new-in-vers,version-number.v1-6"> 
          "user" : "hub", 
          "group" : "gateway-hub",</MadCap:conditionalText> 
          "ssl": { 
              "key_store": "/tmp/ssl_keystore", 
              "trust_store": "/tmp/ssl_truststore" 
          } 
      }<MadCap:conditionalText MadCap:conditions="version-number.v1-6,state.deleted-in-vers"> 
      "ansible" : {  
          "variables" : {  
              "hub_user": "hub",  
              "hub_group": "gateway-hub" 
          }  
      }</MadCap:conditionalText> 
  }</pre> 
                          </div> 
                          <div MadCap:conditions="state.deleted-in-vers,version-number.v1-9"> 
                              <h4>Example using SSH key</h4> 
                              <p>In the next example:</p> 
                              <ul> 
                                  <li>The SSH key for the setup user is located at <code>~/.ssh/HUB-SETUP-KEY.pem</code> on the installation machine, specified with <code>connection.private_key</code>. </li> 
                                  <li>The hosts have an installation user <code>hub-setup</code>. We must provide the FQDN of the host.</li> 
                                  <li>The hosts are specified in a list in a newline-delimited file at <code>/tmp/hosts</code> on the installation machine. </li> 
                                  <li>The KeyStore we are installing to the <MadCap:variable name="Components/gateway-hub.gateway-hub-name" /> hosts is located at <code>/tmp/ssl_keystore</code> on the installation machine.</li> 
                                  <li>The TrustStore we are installing to the <MadCap:variable name="Components/gateway-hub.gateway-hub-name" /> hosts is located at <code>/tmp/ssl_truststore</code> on the installation machine.</li> 
                                  <li>We are providing the passwords.</li> 
                                  <li>There is a runtime user on every host called <code>hub</code>.<ul><li>The runtime user is in group <code>gateway-hub</code>.</li></ul></li> 
                              </ul> 
                              <p>The <MadCap:variable name="3rd-party-products/formats.json-name" /> configuration file is the following:</p><pre xml:space="preserve">{ 
      "connection": { 
          "private_key": "~/.ssh/HUB-SETUP-KEY.pem", 
          "user": "hub-setup" 
      }, 
      "hosts_file": "/tmp/hosts", 
      "hub": {<MadCap:conditionalText MadCap:conditions="state.new-in-vers,version-number.v1-6"> 
          "user" : "hub", 
          "group" : "gateway-hub",</MadCap:conditionalText> 
          "ssl": { 
              "key_store": "/tmp/ssl_keystore", 
                      "key_store_password" "hub123",  
              "trust_store": "/tmp/ssl_truststore", 
              "trust_store_password": "hub123", 
              "key_password": "hub123" 
          } 
      }<MadCap:conditionalText MadCap:conditions="version-number.v1-6,state.deleted-in-vers"> 
      "ansible" : {  
          "variables" : {  
              "hub_user": "hub",  
              "hub_group": "gateway-hub"  
          }  
      }</MadCap:conditionalText> 
  }</pre> 
                          </div>
```

Comment: change this `.format(vers,state)`  to this `.format(state, vers)`

Comment: The target docs uses both orderings of attributes, see the example I provided. Eventually I'll need to deal with that but it's not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the task easier to do using *lxml*, due to easier deleting of an element.

Try the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as et

def remove_element(el):
    parent = el.getparent()
    if el.tail.strip():
        prev = el.getprevious()
        if prev is not None:
            prev.tail = (prev.tail or '') + el.tail
        else:
            parent.text = (parent.text or '') + el.tail
    parent.remove(el)

# Read source XML
parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = et.parse('Input.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
# Replace the below namespace with your proper one
ns = {'mc': 'http://dummy.com'}
# Processing
for it in root.findall('.//*[@mc:conditions]', ns):
    attr = it.attrib
    attrTxt = ', '.join([ f'{key}: {value}'
        for key, value in attr.items() ])
    print(f'Elem.: {et.QName(it).localname:6}: {attrTxt}')
    delFlag = False
    cond = attr.get('{http://dummy.com}conditions')
    if cond:
        dct = { k: v for k, v in (x.split('.')
            for x in cond.split(',')) }
        vn = dct.get('version-number')
        st = dct.get('state')
        if vn == 'v1-6' and st.startswith('deleted'):
            delFlag = True
        print(f"    {vn}, {st:15}  {'Delete' if delFlag else 'Keep'}")
        if delFlag:
            remove_element(it)
# Print the result
print(et.tostring(tree, method='xml',
    encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Of course, in the target version add saving this tree to an
output file.

To have properly formatted XML, with a **single** root element,
I enveloped your content in:

```
<main xmlns:MadCap="http://dummy.com">
   ...
</main>
```

## Edit

In my previous solution I used `it.getparent().remove(it)` to remove
the element in question.
But then I discovered a flaw, which becomes visible if the source
XML contains "mixed content", namely, the "tail" text after the deleted element also was removed (but it should not).

To prevent it, I added *remove_element* function to drop **only** the
element itself and call it instead of previous *it.getparent().remove(it)*.

## An explanation following a question in the comment

The source to *attrTxt* is the content of *attr* dictionary (attributes of the current element).
This fragment actually prints this dictionary without surrounding braces.
It is for trace only, nowhere further it is used.

On the other hand, *dct* plays more important role.
Its source is *cond*, holding content of *conditions* attribute (of the
current element), e.g. *state.new-in-vers,version-number.v1-6*.

This fragment of code:

- Splits the content on a comma.
- Splits each of the above parts on a dot.
- Creates a dictionary from these pairs.

Then *vn* receives the version number (*v1-6*) and *st* - the state
(*new-in-vers*).
It is a substantial piece of intelligence embedded here.
Since both these fragments can occur in different order, you can not create
any *XPath* expression matching every possible case.
But if you check the above variables, it becomes obvious whether this
element should be remover or not.

Comment: Thanks Valdi_Bo this worked great. Although I don't follow some of what you have written. particularly the string manipulation used in attrTxt and dct

Comment: I encountered the tail problem  I think you need another layer of 'if' nesting since if el.tail returns none you get an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Thanks for the additional explanation too, I turned out I needed some additional error checking here too since split generates an error if the conditions attribute is present but blank. I just checked len(cond) to do that.

Comment: You're right. *el.tail* indeed can return *None*, so some protection is needed. Apologies for delay in answer (last week I was "out" without Internet access).